# uv situation causing issue

Tags: uv

After applying  checker patter for uv check, upon selecting the next item, the previous item still displays in uv image editor. How do I get the newly selected object to display and remove the previous object from the window?

Answer (score 0):

in the UV image editor, the UV map will only appear in Edit mode. While in edit mode, you can't select other objects. To do so, press TAB to exit edit mode (you will now stop seeing the UV map of previous object), select the other object, press TAB to enter Edit mode and now you will see the UVmap for that object (if there is one created)